# Disable waiting and writing 'C' in u-boot SPL? - am335x, u-boot v2014.07

Tags: embedded, boot-loader, u-boot

I use u-boot 2014.07 from denx git repository in our board. This u-boot gives me after compilation two files : u-boot.bin and MLO. MLO is first bootloader. I put both on sdcard first partition formated as FAT32.

When my board - chiliboard from grinn company - boots, SPL runs and writes 'C' many times with 1s delay. I can interrupt this process by pressing a key(sending a character on debug serial console). SPL starts booting uboot when i interrupt this process or after about 10s of waiting.

How to disable this 10s waiting time? I want to load u-boot immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer here -> https://e2e.ti.com/support/arm/sitara_arm/f/791/t/471656

Problem was wrong SYSBOOT settings. ROM was waiting for SPL to be sent via the serial port and producing the 'C's as part of the X-MODEM protocol.